# Swift: Last cell in tableView gets userInteraction disabled when it shouldn't

Tags: swift, uitableview, isuserinteractionenabled

I have a tableview with two sections and I want the user interaction of the textView inside the cells of the second section to be disabled (those are completed, users are not meant to be able to edit their text). And the code below from cellForRowAt works fine, but when I add a new cell (which gets added to the end of section 0, this somehow ends up having userInteraction disabled, and I can't figure out why. Reloading the viewController (closing the page and opening it again) seems to fix the problem.

Any ideas or thoughts on why this might be happening?
Thanks in advance.

If any further details are needed, I'm happy to share them.

Here is the code from cellForRow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ActionCell", for: indexPath) as! StepCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.label.alpha = 1

        // This code is needed to remove the strikethrough from this cell
        let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: (cell.label.attributedText)!)
        let originalRange = NSMakeRange(0, attr.length)
        attr.setAttributes([:], range: originalRange)
        cell.label.attributedText = attr
        cell.label.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "", attributes: [:])

        cell.label.text = goals[selectedCell].steps![indexPath.row].title
        cell.checkbox.image = UIImage(named: "unticked")
        cell.focus.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.label.alpha = 0.5
        cell.label.attributedText = goals[selectedCell].completedSteps![indexPath.row].title.withStrikethroughStyle(.single)
        cell.checkbox.image = UIImage(named: "ticked")
        cell.focus.isHidden = true
        cell.label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    cell.label.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: -6, bottom: 20, right: 0);
    cell.label.textColor = .white
    cell.label.tintColor = UIColor(named: "Yellow")
    cell.label.keyboardAppearance = .dark
    cell.label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    cell.label.disableKeyboardAccessory()

    cell.label.delegate = self
    cell.delegate = self

    print("For \(indexPath) user intercation enabled is \(cell.label.isUserInteractionEnabled)")

    return cell

}
```

And here is the code for the action to add a new cell

```
@IBAction func plusTU(_ sender: Any) {

    goals[selectedCell].steps?.append(Step(title: ""))

    let numberOfCells = tableview.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)

    tableview.reloadData()
    tableview.layoutIfNeeded()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.2) {
        let cell = self.tableview.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: numberOfCells, section: 0)) as? StepCell
        cell?.label.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: goals[selectedCell].steps!.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableview.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

    progressBar.configure(goalsIndex: selectedCell)
    configureCompleteGoalButton(buttonHeight: completeGoalButtonHeight, progressBarHeight: progressBarHeight, progressBar: progressBar)
}
```

If it's relevant, I have a textView delegate that looks like this:

```
extension GoalDetails: UITextViewDelegate {


func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let cell = textView.superview?.superview as? StepCell
    let indexPath = tableview.indexPath(for: cell!)
    goals[selectedCell].steps![indexPath!.row].title = textView.text
    resizeTableViewCell()
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" || text == "\t" {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    writeJSONGoals()
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    if descriptionExists == true {
        descriptionHeight.isActive = true
        descriptionExpanded = false
    }

}
}
```

and that function it's calling is this:

```
func resizeTableViewCell(){
    tableview.beginUpdates()
    tableview.endUpdates()
    tableview.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The page looks like this and I'm also attaching a print from the console from cellForRow
[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells get reused.  You need to make sure to explicitly set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to the appropriate value for all cells to make sure they're not using a stale value.

For cells of section `0`, you need to set:

```
cell.label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding this in my textView delegate (that's when they'd lose interaction) and it seems to work. Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: The best way to do it is what I recommended.  Your cells should be fully initialized in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Oh you mean add that before the if statement? Because otherwise I already have cell.label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true in cellForRow, but it's an if statement that changes it based on the section. What am I missing here?

Comment: In the code you posted above, you are only setting `cell.label.isUserInteractionEnabled` in the `else` clause of the `if`.  I suggest you set it to `true` in the first clause (the cause when section is 0).